# How to get all filenames from subarray and count?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following array called `$thumbs_meta` and I want to get all of the filenames from the `sizes` subarray so that I can count them and glue them together into a comma-separated string.

```
Array
(
    [width] => 1024
    [height] => 768
    [file] => 2018/08/Penguins.jpg
    [sizes] => Array
        (
            [thumbnail] => Array
                (
                    [file] => Penguins-150x150.jpg
                    [width] => 150
                    [height] => 150
                    [mime-type] => image/jpeg
                )

            [medium] => Array
                (
                    [file] => Penguins-300x225.jpg
                    [width] => 300
                    [height] => 225
                    [mime-type] => image/jpeg
                )

            [medium_large] => Array
                (
                    [file] => Penguins-768x576.jpg
                    [width] => 768
                    [height] => 576
                    [mime-type] => image/jpeg
                )

            [large] => Array
                (
                    [file] => Penguins-1024x768.jpg
                    [width] => 1024
                    [height] => 768
                    [mime-type] => image/jpeg
                )

            [twentyseventeen-thumbnail-avatar] => Array
                (
                    [file] => Penguins-100x100.jpg
                    [width] => 100
                    [height] => 100
                    [mime-type] => image/jpeg
                )

        )
)
```

I tried foreach, but it's one step more so it's not working.  Should I loop twice?

Here is my present foreach which does not work:

```
foreach($thumbs_meta as $key => $value) {
        $fullname .=$value['file'].',';

                            }
     $thumbs_count = count( $thumbs_meta );
```

Specifically, I want to isolate the `file` values from these keys: `thumbnail`, `medium`, `large`, `medium_large`, and `twentyseventeen-thumbnail-avatar`

My expected count would be `5`

My comma-separated string would be:

```
Penguins-150x150.jpg,Penguins-300x225.jpg,Penguins-768x576.jpg,Penguins-1024x768.jpg,Penguins-100x100.jpg
```

Comment: Your exact desired result is what?  Does `Penguins-100x100.jpg` qualify?  Literally, the is only one `thumbnail` in your sample data, so I don't see the point in looping.  Is this a realistic depication of your project data?

Comment: @mickmackusa under sizes array u can see thumbnails, medium, medium_large, large etc and inside all there is file name. i want to count the file name and list all files seperated by comma . in this case output will be count 5 and file names=Penguins-150x150.jpg,Penguins-300x225.jpg,Penguins-768x576.jpg,Penguins-1024x768.jpg,Penguins-100x100.jpg

Comment: Looks like maybe both of your references to `$thumbs_meta` should really be `$thumbs_meta['sizes']`?

Comment: @GregSchmidt but it will list all file names under sizes ???

Comment: If the array you've shown is the `$thumbs_meta`, then `foreach($thumbs_meta['sizes'] as $key => $value)` will sequentially have `thumbnail`, `medium`, `medium_large`, etc. as the `$key`, and the `$value` will be the arrays which include `'file'`, as your code seems to expect.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705814/create-a-comma-separated-string-from-a-single-column-of-an-array-of-objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) on the `sizes` subarray will get you want in a very succinct and readable fashion.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/l63LE))

```
$thumbnail_files = array_column($thumbs_meta['sizes'], 'file');
var_export($thumbnail_files);

echo "\nCount: " , count($thumbnail_files) , "\n\n";
echo "Imploded: " , implode(',', $thumbnail_files);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'Penguins-150x150.jpg',
  1 => 'Penguins-300x225.jpg',
  2 => 'Penguins-768x576.jpg',
  3 => 'Penguins-1024x768.jpg',
  4 => 'Penguins-100x100.jpg',
)
Count: 5

Imploded: Penguins-150x150.jpg,Penguins-300x225.jpg,Penguins-768x576.jpg,Penguins-1024x768.jpg,Penguins-100x100.jpg
```