# How can I output a comma separated string of values with opneTBS

Tags: opentbs, tinybutstrong

using openTBS (in the SugarCRM plugin MailMergeReports) and I have the following in my Word template.

```
[a_sub5;block=w:p;nodata] No States
[a_sub5;block=w:p][a_sub5.name]
```

This works fine as far as it goes - it outputs a single state name per line - which is fine when the data only has a few states.

The problem is I want it to output the list of states as a comma separated string rather than 1 state per line.  I have tried multiple options with no luck!  Is this not possible to do? or am I just missing the obvious syntax needed to accomplish it.

Note: because I am using TB via a 3rd party plugin to SugarCRM CE I do not have ready access to the PHP code. I need a solution that can be accomplished just within the template specification.

Answer (score 0):

If you had no the `nodata` section, you could try with `[a_sub5.nom;block=!w:r],` but this would add an extra coma at the end of the list. This doesn’t work since you have the `nodata` section because the 2 TBS sections  are not continuous, thus it will produce an invalid XML.

My advice is to format your list at the TBS side, then merge it into the template :

PHP :

```
$list = array_column($data, 'name');
$list = implode(', ', $list);
if ($list == '') $list = "No States";
TBS->MergeField('a_sub5', $list);
```

Template:

```
[a_sub5]
```

If is a sub-block, then you can use a [onformat](https://www.tinybutstrong.com/manual.php#html_field_prm_onformat) custom function for making the list.

Comment: The recommendation of `implode(array_column())` has been given over a hundred times on Stack Overflow.  If this was the resolving advice, then please close this page with with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705814/create-a-comma-separated-string-from-a-single-column-of-an-array-of-objects (the earliest reference that I have found). Truth is, the asker says that they are seeking a non-PHP solution.